# How can I compare two feature classes in arc gis using python

Tags: python, arcgis, shapefile

I have two large shapefiles and want to find the differences. the tools within arc wont let me return a shapefile( Feature class).  Is here some python code which can help me with this.

just tried feature through arc

```
arcpy.FeatureCompare_management('Streets_2019', 'Streeets_2014', 'Shape_Length;EXPAND_INC;OBJECTID;LINK_ID;INPROCDATA;BRIDGE;JUNCTIONNM;ADDR_TYPE;URBAN;ENH_GEOM;ROUNDABOUT', 'ALL', 'IGNORE_Z;IGNORE_POINTID', '0.000000008983 Meters', '0.001', '0.001', '#', '#', 'NO_CONTINUE_COMPARE', '#')
```

I expect a shapefile showing the difference between the two and nothing else

Comment: This looks like an easy question for the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the issue, but one solution is:

Union the 2 shapefiles
Select where one of the two FID fields returned equals -1